# EF & LINQ: Get object from database cell

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, object

I use Entity Framework Code First and I have three tables (for example):

```
public class Motorbike()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Producent {get; set;}
    public Engine Motor {get; set;}
    public Tire Tires {get; set;}
}

public class Engine()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Power {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class Tire()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Size {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

It's just example, in fact it's more complicated.
Entity Frmaework generates table for me, but tables `Motorbike` has column: `Id`, `Power`, `Engine_Id` (where storing only number - id engine, not whole object) and `Tire_Id` (where storing only number - id tire, not whole object).

I know how to insert data - just create new Motorbike object, save to his fields data (for `Engine` and `Tire` fields I save whole objects not only id) and use `.Add()` method from my context.

But how to **get** data for row where motorbike id is (for example) 1?

I've tried something like this:

```
List<Motorbike> motorbikes= new List<Motorbike>();
var list = _context.Motorbike.Where(p => p.Id == 1);
motorbikes.AddRange(list);
```

but always I've got null for `Engine` and `Tire` fields (fields Id and Producent are fill properly).

Comment: Can you supply more information on your entity framework and db definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Include` to load related entities like:

```
var list = _context.Motorbike
                   .Include(m=> m.Engine)
                   .Include(m=> m.Tire)
                   .Where(p => p.Id == 1);
```

See: [Entity Framework - Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Beat me by a minute :)

Comment: @Habib: every day is a school day :) Thanks a lot. As an additional info: it's necessary to add `using System.Data.Entity;` for avoid `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type` error.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220213%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method.

```
List<Motorbike> motorbikes = _context.Motorbike
    .Include(p => p.Engine)
    .Include(p => p.Tire)
    .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
    .ToList();
```